# PrestaShop : Display the shop name in a module

Tags: smarty, prestashop

How can I display the shop name in a module?

I know the global variable of smarty is `$shop_name`.
I tried with `$Smarty.shop_name`, but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in PHP it is `$shop_name`

You need to in PHP run:

```
$Smarty->assign('shop_name', $shop_name);
```

And in Smarty template:

```
{$shop_name}
```

(I don't know Prestashop so maybe $Smarty should be lower-case)

Answer (score 3):

I know it is old but it can be directly got in the tpl with:

```
{Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME')}
```

It does the trick but it is better to send it using the smarty assign function

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/74434224/13903942 f

Answer (score 2):

How about `PS_SHOP_NAME`? I believe it is loaded by the `FrontController` and available in every front office page.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update 2022 (version 8)

As per version 8.00 this is working (and it should be used this way anyway)
Use this variable in a `.tpl`template

```
{$shop.name}
```

That's it!